# Upload to SoundCloud using Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, web-audio-api

Is there a way to upload a sound file recorded using [Recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) and Web Audio API to SoundCloud using Javascript SDK?

Comment: Doesn't look like the SoundCloud JS library exposes this functionality directly -- only the ability to use *their* recording script and then upload. But I bet if you played around with it a bit and watched the network panel in your dev tools, you could figure out what their API endpoint is and what params it expects. Then just do the upload yourself.

Comment: @KevinEnnis the JS SDK uses Flash to record audio. I am looking for a way to replace the recorder audio with my BLOB... but have not got any chance yet. I am also looking for SC.post method... But no success yet.

Comment: Yeah, I understood the question. My point is: try recording something with their Flash thing and upload it. While you're doing that, watch the network panel or use wireshark to see where the file is being posted and what the post data looks like. Then, you can just hit that same API endpoint with your own blob.